# Twitter client tends to redirect to web browser

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, twitter

When clicking a Twitter's link on GMail client, [Twitter client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twitter.android&hl=en) is included in the list of possible applications to process. So I click Twitter but then the list window pops up again but this time without Twitter in it. I really like to open a link to Twitter with Twitter client. How can I do that? Thank you!

A sample of those Twitter links looks like this:
https://twitter.com/i/redirect?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FRescue_moco%3Frefsrc%3Demail&sig=d4724ad41f731911a0eeacd4eb0764b30186d3af&uid=37758565&iid=am-1618412813699712373452051&nid=23+1100&t=1

Nexus 10, Jelly Bean, Twitter client 4.1.0

Comment: @Dan Hulme I updated my question to add a sample URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Twitter app registers an *intent filter* for http and https URLs to `twitter.com`, to tell Android it can open those URLs itself. That's why you get the first *chooser* (the list of possible apps).

However, it seems that the Twitter app can't actually understand those "redirect" links, so it asks for a web browser to handle the URL. That's why you get the second chooser, with only web browsers.

Since the page does in fact redirect to a Twitter user (which the app can handle), after you've opened the URL in a browser you should get a third chooser, which does include Twitter, allowing you to open the user in the Twitter app. However, Firefox currently has a bug that means it won't offer a chooser in this case. If you pick Chrome in the second chooser, it should give you the third chooser.

I'd call this a bug in the Twitter app. You should [complain to Twitter](https://support.twitter.com/forms/apps) and ask them to fix it.

Comment: Good explanation. However, I just found that Chrome does the same.

Comment: In what way? Do you mean that if you pick it in the second chooser, you don't get a third? I'm afraid I don't have the Twitter app installed to test this out.

Comment: Yes with `Chrome` I don't get 3rd chooser, and the 2nd one only suggests web browsers (Chrome, FFox). I've sent a request to `Twitter` from the link you provided (their ticket No. is #9797760 if there's a way to refer to it online).

Comment: That's interesting. I'd have expected it to work like `youtu.be` shortened URLs, where clicking the shortened URL gives you a chooser of just browsers, and then Youtube redirects you to the full `youtube.com/watch` URL, and you get a second chooser including the YouTube app. Maybe Twitter's redirects work differently.